# Swift - How to display thumbnail capture of video in table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, video, avplayer

From the initial research I've done, I see where the AVPlayer control is provided by Apple to play video through the iPhone. I would like to be able to able to embed a thumbnail of the videos in a UITableView. The problem I'm running into is that I can't drag and drop the AVPlayer component onto my custom table view cell. It appears that the AVPlayer control needs to be dropped onto the storyboard like a separate view controller.

It is my understanding that the AVPlayer component has the ability to capture a thumbnail of the video, but if I can't drag and drop the AVPlayer component onto my custom table view cell, how can I grab the thumbnail and display it in the cell? Would I use a UIImageView somehow? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by using MPMoviePlayerController instead of AVPlayer. Using MPMoviePlayerController, I was able to grab the thumbnail image by specifying the number of seconds into the video to grab the frame to be used for the thumbnail. I then assigned the image obtained to a UIImageView. Hope this helps someone.